# how to find different object in NSMutableArray and add to another NSMutableArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have one problem and I want to search every object in my `NSMutableArray`.
if this object (the object for searching) no "0" add to another `NSMutableArray` with name : **StarArray**

this is my first `NSMutableArray`

```
(
        (
        1,
        1,
        6
    ),
        (
        0
    ),
        (
        0,
        3
    ),
        (
        5,
        3
    ),
        (
        0
    )
)
```

this `NSMutableArray` is 2d (matrix) and I want get every object except object that have 0 value and add to **StarArray**

```
StarArray : {1,1,6,3,5,3}
```

Comment: What have you tried?  This is not a site to get others to do your work for you.

Comment: I know but I so confused I write two for loop inside together and check every object that if no "0" add to another nsmutablearray but not working!!! pls guide me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, it may work:

```
NSMutableArray *StarArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (int i = 0; i < [firstArray count] ; i++) {
    for (id object in [firstArray objectAtIndex:i]) {
        if (![object isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
            [StarArray addObject:object];
        }
    }
}
NSLog(@"%@", StarArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this 
It will take less iterations to execute

```
NSMutableArray *resultArr = [NSMutableArray array];

for(NSArray *arr in yourArr)
{
    NSMutableArray *ar = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:arr];
    while( [ar containsObject:@"0"])
    {
        [ar removeObject:@"0"];
    }
    if([ar count])
       [resultArr addObjectsFromArray:ar];
}
```